# Best way to process raw CDN logs stored in Azure Blob Storage to an Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have an Azure CDN and all my **raw logs** (every request made to the CDN) goes to my **Azure Blob Storage** formatted as "JSON Lines". (these are AzureCdnAccessLog)

I am looking to process those logs (every 10-20 minutes) to count the number of times each resource has been accessed, when and from which platform etc... and output the result to my **Azure SQL Database**.

What is the best solution to batch process those logs on Azure?

Thank you in advance for your aswers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [Azure function Blob storage trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob) is the best candidate. But keep in mind that azure function has limitation for [how long it can run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale)

```
[FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]        
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("container/{name}")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

The other option would be [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/data-factory/), Here is [more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) about how to import from blob

Comment: I thought about this solution but as you mentioned if my dataset is huge, I will reach the limitations  (which is likely to happen as we're talking about raw logs from a CDN). The miracle solution would be something like Big Query integrated with my Azure blob storage but I don't know anything like that on azure...

Comment: Thank you I will check this out 